# Eigenvalues of $\operatorname{diag}({\bf v}) - {\bf v} {\bf v}^\top - \alpha({\bf v} - {\bf w})({\bf v} - {\bf w})^\top$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Given vectors ${\bf v}, {\bf w} \in [0,1]^n$ , where $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, and $\alpha > 0$, I would like to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix.

$$\operatorname{diag}({\bf v}) - {\bf v} {\bf v}^\top - \alpha({\bf v} - {\bf w})({\bf v} - {\bf w})^\top$$

I can have the eigenvalues of ${\bf v} {\bf v}^\top - \operatorname{diag}({\bf v})$ and $\alpha({\bf v}-{\bf w})({\bf v}-{\bf w})^\top$ separately to maybe bound the eigenvalues, but I am seeking for a closed form, especially for the smallest one.

Comment: I don't believe that such a closed form formula can exist, at least for what I would consider any reasonable definition of "closed form". For example, if $\mathbf{v} = (1,-1,2,-1,1)$ and $\mathbf{w} = (-1,1,0,-1,1)$ and $\alpha = 1$ then this matrix has characteristic polynomial $x^5 + 18x^4 + 6x^3 - 56x^2 + 9x + 6$, which I believe (I haven't checked super carefully) has Galois group $S_5$ and so the roots cannot be expressed in terms of radicals.

Comment: yes, it's a rank-1 or rank-2 update of the diagonal matrix.

Comment: @CereIssou Then, using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), you may find the characteristic polynomial in closed-form.  Finding the roots in closed-form, however...

Answer (score 0):

The **smallest** eigenvalue can be found (approximately) via the following [semidefinite program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) (SDP).

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {t} {\text{maximize}} & t \\ \text{subject to} & \operatorname{diag}({\bf v}) - {\bf v} {\bf v}^\top - \alpha({\bf v} - {\bf w})({\bf v} - {\bf w})^\top \succeq t \, {\bf I}_n \end{array} $$

Comment: It can also be found by minimizing the Rayleigh quotient, no need to use something more complicated.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Do you mean the following? $$\min_{ \| {\bf x} \|_2 = 1} {\bf x}^\top {\bf A} \, {\bf x}$$

Comment: Yes! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient .

Comment: @FedericoPoloni But it's a non-convex QCQP.  I can use a Lagrange multiplier and obtain $\bf (A - \mu I) x = 0$, but how do I find the minimal $\mu$?

Comment: You can remove the constraint by minimizing $\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$, and convert it to the largest eigenvalue by shifting the matrix (by an amount that you can determine via norm estimates). Then there are various methods in linear algebra literature, the simplest one being the power method. But even minimizing the Rayleigh quotient with standard optimization techniques works fine, I have given similar problems to students as final projects in the past.

Comment: Also, what is the complexity of solving this SDP? Does it beat $O(n^3)$ which would be the complexity of just computing the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yeah, this is overkill. Yet, it works even if the matrix is a linear combination of given matrices,, provided that it is symmetric. And it requires no knowledge of numerical linear algebra. I understand that numerical linear algebra is your field, but sometimes one has a problem to solve and does not have the time to take a course on NLA.  In that case, better reduce the problem to LP, convex QP, SDP, etc, and let the solver handle it.  The mathematical knowledge is in the solver, not the human user.